# Pyomo load function

Tags: pyomo

I have got a file named test.xls which looks like this:

```
    All 
    Index                       MaxProd
    Nuclear                     300,0
    DomesticCoal_Anthracite     588,0
    BrownLignite                203,1
    ImportedCoal_SubBituminous  150,4
    ImportedCoal_Bituminous     194,4
    CCGT_1                      500,0
    CCGT_2                      500,0
    CCGT_3                      500,0
    CCGT_4                      667,5
    OCGT_1                      400,0
    OCGT_2                      400,0
    OCGT_3                      400,0
    FuelOilGas                  441,8
```

Where All (and rest) is in column A and MaxProd column B. But when I try to read the data in with my little script:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = AbstractModel()
model.Index = Set()
model.MaxProd = Param(model.Index)

data = DataPortal(model=model)
data.load(filename="Test.xls", range="All", format='set', set=model.Index)
```

It gives me the error message:

OSError: Unknown range name All'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?